# How to create MATLAB static text with editable font style

Tags: html, matlab, user-interface

MATLAB® provides a static text `uicontrol` (created by using the uicontrol with style text: `uicontrol('Style','text','Label','static text'…)`, which does not allows you to use neither `html` nor `tex` interpretation. What is your solution for creating static text interpretable with some language which allows you to change the font style and color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh? Have you tried this?

```
h =  uicontrol('Style','text','String','hello');
set(h,'Foregroundcolor','r','FontSize',10,'Fontname','Helvetica','Fontweight','bold');
```

Is this what you want? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah ok, quite easier… but the matlab documentation is quite confusing. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: *Matlab documentation on this topic `uicontrol`

Comment: Welcome! With a Matlab UI object `h` it's often useful to type `set(h)`. That shows all properties and their possible values, which gives you an idea of what you can set.

Answer (score 0):

My approach works creating a pushbutton and editing its java object so that it looks like a static link. Probably there are other solutions, fill free to improve the topic if you want to do so.

In order to do so, you will need [findjobj at Matlab FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317).

Then get the java component from your `uicontrol` handle, and remove its Border:

```
pushButtonH=uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','Label','<html>static text',…)
jPushButton = findjobj(pushButtonH);
jPushButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

An example using the label as: `<html><i><font color="red"> GUI example`:

[image: Static Text with color]